# Stop Microsoft Graph API token from expiring

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, access-token, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm sending notifications from Zendesk into Teams using the webhooks on Zendesk. From Zendesk, you can make external API calls using webhooks. this requires Endpoint URL, authentication method and method.

I can use the Graph API to connect to Teams, however, the token keeps expiring. Is there any way to prevent this expiration?

I ask because, the webhook is set up via the API, so the connection setup needs to be static i.e. saved once and reused as required.

I'm still in testing mode so I can get a new token (manually) and update the webhook setup. Of course, this is not sustainable in a live environment.

Is there any way to keep the token active 'forever'

Comment: Tokens **have to** expire, otherwise they'd cause a disaster if they were leaked. I assume you're using OIDC/OAuth? If so, are you using `client_credentials` or otherwise have a `refresh_token`?

Comment: The token expires after an hour. After that you need to renew the token. There is a API-call where you can renew this, in swift it's acquireTokenSilent().

Comment: I literally just got a token from Graph Explorer to test my workflows. The only options available to me are endpoint URL, authentication type, the request method, request format and associated authentication details (uname+pw, bearer token etc). All are set up via the UI so no options to request/renew details other than going to the UI every few hours/days and updating the token. How would an integration work if the authentication method has to be renewed frequently and where there is no accessible code base to make this 'renew' request?

Comment: @rupertnorth Headless (i.e. non-human-operated) software using OAuth2 would acquire an `access_token` via `client_credentials` rather than using OIDC `code` or `implicit` grants as with a human user - this includes Microsoft's Graph API:  read this:  "[Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)" - and this [the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

Comment: Thanks @Dai. Unless I'm misunderstanding your comment, I think what I'm trying to do may not be possible. For this OAuth2 flow, a redirect URI  is required (in Azure) where the response with the access token is sent. However as this is all done via a UI, I don't have any way to store the returned access token as there is nothing available to provide to external systems in this case Graph API.